# Debugging BL2 using lauterbach

Tags: bootloader

```
I am trying to debug bl2. loaded bl2 binary on to target and continues loop with a variable.

then attached using lauterbach and loaded bl2.elf, bl2 compiled with DEBUG=1 option, which 

means symbols are enabled, but when loaded all symbols are not loaded. Please point to me, if i 

am missing anything.

below is the script used.

sys.cpu XYZ-A53

core.assign 1

SYStem.config.debugporttype JTAG

SYStem.Option TRST OFF

sys.attach

Data.Load.Elf bl2.elf  /GLOBTYPES /NoClear /NoCODE

break

list

ENDDO
```